# Trying to install yolov3 via anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, object-detection, yolo

I'm doing my thesis project on object detection and I've decided to use this git hub (https://github.com/reigngt09/yolov3workflow/tree/master/2_YoloV3_Execute) to install yolov3.

However, I'm not able to excute the code `conda env create -f yolo.yml`

So I tried to use `pip install -r requirements.txt` but that came up with an error too.

The error I got was

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 52)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 52))
```

If anyone has any advice, I would really appreciate it. Or if anyone has another more recent git hub I can follow that would be great news!

Comment: That version is not on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/#history) (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Try running with a different version, as per https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/ the current version is 1.0.6, replace the line in requirements.txt and make it mkl-fft==1.0.6